# link or install local typescript library inside docker container

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, shared-libraries, node-modules

I'm still dockerizing our microfrontend application. Currently we use React and Angular and a shared library for the communication. The library is developed by ourself and installed locally via npm.

```
'- angular-project
'- react-projects
'- shared-libs
   '- communication-lib
```

We are installing the communication-lib locally with

```
npm install ..\shared-libs\communication-lib
```

Running everything locally works fine. But as we move to docker, there are several issues and I can't figure out a good solution. Below are the first few lines of the angular projects Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend
COPY ./angular/package.json ./angular/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i
...
# already crashed here
```

This is the point where docker fails because the lib is not known to the docker image.
I also added a volume to share the code of the shared lib with this image, but then i still have the issue of not having a already build node_module.

I'm really thankful if someone could provide me some useful hints how to solve this issue.

**My thougths:**

Is it somehow possible to create a standalone docker for the libs and use these container in my angular projects container?

Can I somehow copy/build and link the lib inside the container ?

Comment: You can 1) publish your library and install it from a repo 2) have it in the docker image with the project at the path specified for the package

Comment: 1) Is no Option, its a mono repo
2) But how i build and Link everything. When copying the lib to docker, its Not build at this Point. Therefore running "npm i" fails

Comment: If you have a monorepo, then why is it even a library and needs to be built? Should be rather some sorts of shared source files. Libraries are built to share over the network

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this isnt a problem especially when having multiple Apps in Same repo speaking about microfrontends. And If I do so, i need to target the src folder instead of global namespace which is not what I want to achieve. I know i can also modify paths in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can't do exactly what you want, but there are alternatives...

### Explanation

#### The Local Package Link Story

When you add a local package via `npm install ../<folder>` it creates a symbolic link (symlink) inside of `node_modules` to that folder instead of actually copying the content of `../<folder>` over to your `node_modules`. It does that so in case you make an update in your linked package, it seamlessly reflects in your project in real-time.

#### The Docker Build Story

When you run `docker build` it sends the build context to the deamon. The root of the build context it where the `Dockerfile` is located. That means that the deamon has no access to any folder on the filesystem outside of the build context; i.e. a `Dockerfile` located inside of `angular-project` will cause the deamon not to be able to access the `shared-libs` folder, so you will not be able to copy anything from there.

This is also, why a `COPY` or an `ADD` command inside a `Dockerfile` cannot follow symlinks outside of the build context. Meaning it would not be able to copy that content into the image.

### Solutions

#### Moving Up `Dockerfile`

One thing you can do is move the `Dockerfile` to a folder that contains **all** your expected packages, i.e. in your case one folder up where both the `angular-project` is as well as the `shared-libs` folder is. This of course would complicate other things like selecting the `Dockerfile` to build, as well as the commands inside the `Dockerfile` so they copy the correct items and only them into the image.

#### Packing Local Package

Another option, is to pack the `communication-lib` (`npm pack ..\shared-libs\communication-lib`) and then reference the tarball (`npm install communication-lib.tgz`) in `angular-project` instead. See [here](https://getridbug.com/node-js/how-to-force-npm-not-to-create-symbolic-link-to-local-package/).
You can add the tarball to your `.gitignore` if you don't want to check it in, but you will have to run the `npm pack` command on first build and every time there is an update to the shared library.

Comment: Thanks for the deep explaination. I already tried to Set build context to root folder of monorepo. But for development its bad to Always Run npm run pack. It will solve the issue for now, but I guess there will be a smarter solution to this issue. Maybe copying source and build inside of dockerfile. But i want it to also Work without docker in Case of local testing.